# curl on macos Catalina not displaying response body

Tags: macos, curl

Tried to make a curl to https://transfer.sh with curl and the response body disappear from the screen. I made a gif from my terminal: https://giphy.com/gifs/hvjZcaFbRPl9LbsBXg

I'm trying to run this cmd, where test is a text file:

```
curl --upload-file test https://transfer.sh
```

For workaround, I'm using a inline python script, which works pretty well:

```
python -c 'import requests; print(requests.post("https://transfer.sh/", files={"upload_file": open("test","rb")}).text)'
```

Comment: I face the same kind of behavior but only with zsh.
I mean with bash it works as expected.  
  
Do you also feel that it seems to be an issue about "curl"+"zsh" ? (if yes maybe the question should be renamed including zsh)  
  
Does someone know if this is rather a bug of curl or zsh or just expected "incompatibility" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can fix with -w "\n":

```
curl --upload-file test -s -w "\n" https://transfer.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`curl` seems to be giving the terminal a carriage return.  Try stripping out carriage returns using `tr`:

`curl --upload-file test https://transfer.sh | tr -d '\r'`

Comment: Same behaviour. Btw, do you know if zsh do this?